# Tengo este error en laravel: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-9

> Controller

No entiendo porque se daria este error se que hay algo que no estoy podiendo definir estuve
buscando en la ducomentacion de laravel pero aun no puedo encontrar nada. Me gutaria que si me
pudiera dar una mano

```
public function index(){
     $instancias = InstanciaEvaluativa::groupBy('tipo')->get();

     return view('instancia-evaluativa.index', array('instancias' => $instancias));
}
```

> Modelo

Este modelo define donde encontraría copia y justamente es el mismo nombre que deberia de tener
la parte del controlador, no creo que sea por el index ya que es un index bastante simple a la
hora de mostrar la pagina web.

```
protected $table="instancias_evaluativas";
protected $fillable=[
          'nombre', 
            'tipo', 
           'forma', 
           'fecha', 
     'nota_maxima', 
           'copia',
'espacio_curricular_id',  
      'docente_id', 
      'periodo_id'];`
```

Answer (score 0):

### Primera Opción

En `config\database.php` --> En el ARRAY `"mysql"`

Coloca `'strict' => false` para deshabilitar todo.

### Segunda Opción

Puede dejar `'strict' = true` y agregar `'modes'` en el ARRAY de `'mysql'`

```
'mysql' => [
   ...
   ....
   'strict' => true,
   'modes' => [
        //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Deshabilite esto para permitir la agrupación por una columna
        'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
        'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
    ],
]
```

### Respuesta Detallada

Es posible que no necesite deshabilitar todas las opciones estrictas. Por favor, eche un vistazo a esta [respuesta](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997#issuecomment-242129087) sobre este problema.

Comment: Esto me serviría si no interfiriera con otra función dentro de la vista